# Re-ordering form results with Java/JSP

Tags: java, html, jsp

I'm inexperienced with Java and JSP. I created a form and it works the way it is supposed to, but I want to have some fun with it and have it reorder the results after the form is submitted. I'll include some images to show what I mean. I'm having a hard time searching for what I want and don't really know where to start. Any help will be appreciated.

Here is the form page:
[image]

Here is the results: 
[image]

Here is what I want the results to look like (notice 'last' goes from 2 to 3, 'middle' from 3 to 5, 'item' from 4 to 2, and 'address' from 5 to 4):
[image]

Java File

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.util.*;

public class ShowParameters extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {


        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        String docType =
                "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 " +
                "Transitional//EN\">\n";
        String title = "Reading All Request Parameters";

        out.println(docType +
                "<HTML>\n" +
                "<HEAD><TITLE>" + title + "</TITLE></HEAD>\n" +
                "<BODY BGCOLOR=\"#FDF5E6\">\n" +
                "<H1 ALIGN=CENTER>" + title + "</H1>\n" +
                "<TABLE BORDER=1 ALIGN=CENTER>\n" +
                "<TR BGCOLOR=\"#FFAD00\">\n" +
                "<TH>Parameter Name<TH>Parameter Value(s)");

        Enumeration paramNames = request.getParameterNames();
        while(paramNames.hasMoreElements()) {
            String paramName = (String)paramNames.nextElement();
            out.print("<TR><TD>" + paramName + "\n<TD>");
            String[] paramValues =
                    request.getParameterValues(paramName);
            if (paramValues.length == 1) {
                String paramValue = paramValues[0];
                if (paramValue.length() == 0)
                    out.println("<I>No Value</I>");
                else
                    out.println(paramValue);
            } else {
                out.println("<UL>");
                for(int i=0; i<paramValues.length; i++) {
                    out.println("<LI>" + paramValues[i]);
                }
                out.println("</UL>");
            }
        }

        out.println("</TABLE>\n</BODY></HTML>");
    }

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("STOP1\n");
        doGet(request, response);
    }

}
```

JSP file

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Lab 3</title>
<style type="text/css">
.address {
height: 50px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<body BGCOLOR="#FF0000">

<h1 align="center">Basic FORM</h1>
<form action="ShowParameters" method="post">
    First Name: <input type="text" name="first"> <br>
    Last Name: <input type="text" name="last" value="$"> <hr/>
    Middle Name: <input type="text" name="middle"> <br>
    Item: <input type="text" name="item"> <br>
    Address: <input type="text" name="address" class="address"> <br>
    Credit Card: <br> 
    <input type="radio" name="cardType" value="Visa">Visa <br>
    <input type="radio" name="cardType" value="MasterCard">MasterCard <br>
    Credit Card Number: <input type="text" name="cardNum"> <br><br>

    <center><input type="submit" value="Submit Order"></center>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of creating html in servlet create a class to hold form input information like:

```
public class Person {

    private String firstName;
    private String midlleName;
    private String lastName;
    private String item;
    private String address;
    private String cardType;
    private String cardNumber;

    //getters and setters

}
```

in servlet create instance of Person class and set values then simply add person instance to request and forward to jsp.

```
   Person person = new Person();
   person.setFirstName(request.getParameter("first"));
   //set other person values here
   request.setAttribute("person", person);
   request.getRequestDispatcher("filename.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

in jsp display like:

```
<table border="2">
    <tr bgcolor="#FFAD00">
        <th>Parameter Name</th>
        <th>Parameter Value(s)</th>     
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>first</td><td>${person.firstName}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>item</td><td>${person.item}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>last</td><td>${person.midlleName}</td>
    </tr>   
    <tr>
        <td>address</td><td>${person.address}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>middle</td><td>${person.lastName}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>cardType</td><td>${person.cardType}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>cardNum</td><td>${person.cardNumber}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Benefits:

- easy to change the order as you like in html.(simply move the `<tr/>` elements)
- No need of loop.
- Follows Object-oriented programming (OOP) style of programming.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than getting an enumeration of the parameters by `request.getParameterNames` you could have a string array of all the parameter names you expect with them in the order you want, and you could loop through that array like so:

```
String[] paramNames = { "item", "last", "first" };
for(int i=0; i<paramNames.length; i++)
{
     out.print("<tr>");
     out.print("<td>" + paramNames[i] + "</td>");
     out.print("<td>");
     String[] paramValues = request.getParameterValues(paramNames[i]);
     ...
     ...
     out.print("</td>");
     out.print("</tr>");
}
```

Please take note that one of the things you are not doing in your code is properly closing the cells with `</td>` and the rows with `</tr>`.  You should really also close the LIs with `</li>`.

Comment: So which code would I remove exactly? Just the line that says "Enumeration paramNames = request.getParameterNames();"? Or should I remove the while loop immediately following that line as well?

Comment: Also, should I be replacing the two lines of "..." with something?